# ¿Cómo sustituir valores por variables en CURL PHP?

Tags: php, curl

Necesito cambiar valores por variables.
Esto es la ejecución de un CURL.

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.xxxxx",
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>"{\r\n\"Contrato\": 100678829,\r\n\"QtdVezes\": 1\r\n}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array($content,$refresh,$autoriz),
));
```

Tengo una lista de Contrato que seran leidos de una tabla Mysql.
Para esa tarea tendré que cambiar el numero del Contrato por una variable $contr y la cantidad por una variable $qtde.

***¿Como puedo concaternar las dichas variables en el CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS ?.***
Deberia ser algo así:

```
"{\r\n\"Contrato\": $contr,\r\n\"QtdVezes\": $qtde\r\n}",
```

donde el $contr = 100678829 y $qtde = 1, pero me sale un error cuando hago la concatenacion desa manera:

```
'"{\r\n\"Contrato\":'. $contr.',\r\n\"QtdVezes\":'.$qtde,'\r\n}"',
```

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Debes finalizar los parametros antes de los valores de la variable y  agregarles una coma  algo asi  'Authorization: '.  $tok, 'api-key: ssdsd44', no se si te sirva saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.curl-setopt.php) dice lo siguiente sobre `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`:

> Se puede enviar una cadena urlencoded como 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...'
> o también como un array con el nombre del campo como key y los datos
> como value.

Significa que puedes construir los valores como un array, por ejemplo:

```
$toPost=array("Contrato" => $contr, "QtdVezes"=> $qtde);
```

Y ahora pasas `$toPost` del siguiente modo:

```
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>$toPost,
```

También lo puedes construir como una cadena urlencoded:

```
$toPost="Contrato=$contr&QtdVezes=$qtde";
```

O, como un JSON (que es parecido a lo que estabas haciendo, pero no hacen falta los saltos), en ese caso simplemente sería:

```
$toPost=json_decode("{\"Contrato\": $contr,\"QtdVezes\": $qtde}");
```

Y habría que agregar al array que pasas en `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` que el content type es un json:

```
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>$toPost,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array($content,$refresh,$autoriz,'Content-Type: application/json'),
```

Comment: A.Cedano, muchas gracias por el aporte. Pero tengo una duda aún.
No lo sé como concatenar las variables $contr y $qtde dentro de la cadena para que se vea así: "{\r\n\"Contrato\": 100678829,\r\n\"QtdVezes\": 1\r\n}",
cuando el envio me parece que el WS no reconoce las variables convertidas.

Comment: @Bonfim, simplemente así: `$toPost="{\r\n\"Contrato\": $contr,\r\n\"QtdVezes\": $qtde\r\n}";`, tal y como lo tienes. Pero eso es sólo una cadena, no es un valor válido para el WS, si el WS espera un JSON, entonces prueba a mandarlo como te indicaba al final, con `json_decode($toPost)` o directamente convirtiendo la cadena a JSON con `json_decode("{\"Contrato\": $contr,\"QtdVezes\": $qtde}")` Si da error dinos qué error es.

Comment: @A Cedano, he logrado êxito; mas una vez muchas gracia, yo hizo asi:
$contr=100971278;
$qtde=1;
$toPost="{\r\n\"Contrato\": $contr,\r\n\"QtdVezes\": $qtde\r\n}",